# Remove an Node in XML in VB script and Classic ASP

Tags: xml, asp-classic, vbscript

I need to delete an node in an XML, my XML looks as below

```
<message_version>Test</message_version>
<responder_id>My test XML file</responder_id>
</m_control>
<m_content>
<b_control>
    <quote_response_status>error</quote_response_status>
    <quote_error_note>
        <reason>
            <note>
                <text>An error occurred.
                </text>
            </note>
        </reason>
    </quote_error_note>
</b_control>
```

In the above xml i need to remove the node "text" and "note", keepimg the text "An error occurred." untouched. How can i achieve that.

basically i need an XML as below after removing the node 'text' and 'note'

```
<message_version>Test</message_version>
<responder_id>My test XML file</responder_id>
</m_control>
<m_content>
<b_control>
    <quote_response_status>error</quote_response_status>
    <quote_error_note>
        <reason>
            An error occurred.
        </reason>
    </quote_error_note>
</b_control>
```

I have tried the following with no sucess:

```
sXMLPath = "//message/m_content/b_control/quote_error_note/reason"
Set sRemoveText = m_objResponseXML.selectSingleNode(sXMLPath & "/note/text")
Set sRemoveNote = m_objResponseXML.selectSingleNode(sXMLPath & "/note")

If Not sRemoveText is Nothing Then
    m_objResponseXML.selectSingleNode(sXMLPath & "/note").removeChild(sRemoveText)
    sErrorMsg = GetNodeText(sXMLPath & "/note/text", m_objResponseXML)
End if
If Not sRemoveText is Nothing Then
    m_objResponseXML.selectSingleNode(sXMLPath).removeChild(sRemoveNote)
End If

If sErrorMsg <> "" Then
    m_objResponseXML.selectSingleNode(sXMLPath).text = sErrorMsg
End If
```

Any kind of help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To examplify Rafael's advice with code and to give you some search/keywords to look for when reading the Docs:

```
Option Explicit

Dim oXML : Set oXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
If oXML.load(".\005.xml") Then
   WScript.Echo oXML.xml
   Dim ndReason : Set ndReason = oXML.selectSingleNode("/b_control/quote_error_note/reason")
   If ndReason Is Nothing Then
      WScript.Echo "not reasonable"
   Else
      Dim sReason : sReason = ndReason.selectSingleNode("note/text").text
      ndReason.removeChild ndReason.firstChild
      WScript.Echo oXML.xml
      ndReason.appendChild oXML.createTextNode(sReason)
      WScript.Echo oXML.xml
   End If
Else
   WScript.Echo oXML.parseError.reason
End If
```

output:

```
cscript 005.vbs
<b_control>
        <quote_response_status>error</quote_response_status>
        <quote_error_note>
                <reason>
                        <note>
                                <text>An error occurred.
                </text>
                        </note>
                </reason>
        </quote_error_note>
</b_control>

<b_control>
        <quote_response_status>error</quote_response_status>
        <quote_error_note>
                <reason>
                </reason>
        </quote_error_note>
</b_control>

<b_control>
        <quote_response_status>error</quote_response_status>
        <quote_error_note>
                <reason>An error occurred.</reason>
        </quote_error_note>
</b_control>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing data in the way you want, go against the XML/HTML Hierarchy philosophy, where every tag is enclosed in another tag.

the simple solution is copy the string remove the tags and filling the text property of the reason tag to achieve this.

other way, gonna be **evil**

to manipulate XML you can use [MSXML Object Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

### Edit

based on the example shown

```
sXMLPath = "//message/m_content/b_control/quote_error_note/reason"
```

your XPath String is incorrect the correct it's

```
sXMLPath = "//b_control/quote_error_note/reason"
```

Comment: thanks Rafael. I have tired the following code but result is negative, i cant able to delete the node.

Comment: Rafael, i have edited your response with the code changes i have tired. please correct me if there is anything wrong

Comment: @user809244 Code now moved to the body of your question